# How to plot in matplotlib with two dimensional list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have two lists

```
a=[[0,2,4]]
b=[[3,5,7]]
```

when I plot using matplotlib I know I can just get rid of the square brackets, i.e.

```
plt.plot([0,2,4], [3,5,7])
```

but what if I had a large list listed as a variable, say `x`, how to I plot it knowing I would I have to deal with double square brackets?

Comment: Python 5?! What year is this?

Comment: Python 5 ? Damn, I still use old 3.5.

Comment: Haha, I just couldn't find a suitable title that wasnt taken sorry

Comment: Joking aside, it's not clear what you're asking. The answer is probably `plot(*x)`, though. You know the square brackets are the indication of a list right? You don't *"get rid of"* them anywhere.

Comment: `square brackets` are only information for you that you have list (or N-dimensional list) and not single value. You may need to use index - ie. `some_list[0]`

Comment: When you say double square brackets, do you mean `[1, 2, 3][4, 5. 6]` or something like `[[1, 2, 3]]`?

Comment: @Ronikos The second one.

Comment: @iTZMee125 Is it [[1, 2, 3]] or [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]] - these are two dimensional lists, the first is much easier to handle though

Comment: @Ronikos The first one for both x and y values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of the question, the lists are structured like `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

This is an example of a two-dimensional list - albeit it a very useless one. If one consider another two dimensional list: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` The two lists inside the outer list can be treated as items of that list. ie:

```
a = [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]

a[0] --> [1, 2]
a[1] --> [3. 4]
```

So in your example, the simplest way to turn the 2 dimensional list into a one dimensional list is simply take the first element of the list (because the first element is actually the useful list).

```
a = [[1, 2, 3]]
b = [[4, 5, 6]]

plt.plot(a[0], b[0])
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  # is the same as above
```